# ansible print ec2_tag register list

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, tags

i have this simple task which i get ec2 instance tgs 
i like to print out the return list of values .

```
- name: get my tagging
  local_action:
    module: ec2_tag
    region: "{{ region }}"
    resource: "{{ instance_id }}"
    state: list
  register: my_ec2_tags
  tags:
    - spots
```

this don't print me any value

```
- name: Display all ec2_tags
  debug:
    var: my_ec2_tags
    verbosity: 3
```

how can i print all the values of my_ec2_tags so i could know if it was set right ?

Comment: What error are you getting? Or is it not printing anything at all?

Comment: Your task looks fine, and the output must be registered in `my_ec2_tags`. Could you please share, what output are you getting? Without it, there is no point guessing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using tags while running the play. In that case, you should tag your debug task as well.

E.g.:

```
- name: Display all ec2_tags
  debug:
    var: my_ec2_tags.tags
  tags:
    - spots
```

Comment: Thought I bumped up an old question. Removed the disclaimer.