# Define Variable if another variable output is

Tags: ansible

I would be happy if I can define a variable, but I need to be dynamic like:

if {{ var }} = 1 then var2 = summer,
else var2=winter.

I need to define that on top of my task. Is it possible in ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `vars/main.yml`:

```yaml
var2: "{% if var == 1 %}summer{% else %}winter{% endif %}"
```

*Update*:

Setting the port based on runmode:

```yaml
port: "{% if runmode == 'author' %}4502{% else %}4503{% endif %}"
```

Comment: I just updated my answer with the variables you are using. Then the condition would be `if runmode == 'author'`

Comment: Worked. Can it also return variables ?

Comment: Return as in show the value of variables? Use the `debug` module for that. See my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62388227/ansible-print-ec2-tag-register-list/63071767#63071767

Answer (score 2):

Use [*ternary*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) filter. For example

```yaml
- set_fact:
    var2: "{{ (var|int == 1)|ternary('summer', 'winter') }}"
```

The next option is [*Jinja2 if*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/?highlight=endif#if) statement

```yaml
- set_fact:
    var2: "{% if var|int == 1 %}summer{% else %}winter{% endif %}"
```

Comment: Which part? Do you think the documentation should be improved?

Comment: My variable which to check is {{ runmode }} . Can u give an example if runmode is publish. Then port === 4503

Comment: I see. It's up to you. Next time, include all details in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Can you just do this:

```
var2 = none;
if({{var}} == 1)
    var2 = summer;
else
    var2 = winter;
```

Comment: ERROR! failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'dict' and a 'AnsibleUnicode':

Comment: port = author;
if({{ runmode }} == author)
port = 4502;
else
port = 4503;   I put this in vars/main.yml